# save and close images without asking

Tags: dm-script

I try to write some code to save and close top 7 images, as it is below, but when I execute the code, the DM still ask “Save changes to xxx before closing? What command or code I need to add then the code can automatically save the changes of top 7 images without any pop-up ask window. Thanks

```
 image temp:=getfrontimage()
    string imgname=getname(temp)
    string currentpath, currentdirectory
    if(!SaveAsDialog("Save As",imgname,currentpath))exit(0)
    currentdirectory=pathextractdirectory(currentpath,2)
    number i
    string newname, startstring
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            image front:=getfrontimage()
            string imgname=getname(front)       
            string thispath=pathconcatenate(currentdirectory, imgname)
            saveasgatan(front, thispath)
            hideimage(front)
                    closeimage(front)       
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an image from memory, you can *delete* it rather than *close* it. The following removes the front most image without prompting:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
DeleteImage( img )
```

It is also good to know that **image** objects are the actual data array, but **imageDocuments** are the objects which are linked to file and window. It is therefore a command of the imageDocument class which is needed. To close an image (or rather it's imageDocument) without asking to save, you can use:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDocument iDoc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
iDoc.ImageDocumentClose( 0 )    // parameter is Boolean for "askToSave"
```

There is also a command to get you the front most imageDocument right away, so you may also use:

```
GetFrontImageDocument().ImageDocumentClose(0)
```